# How to parse burp suite request from file in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, request, burp

I once knew the name of python3 module that after importing when gave the name of request file saved by burpsuite, it automatically generated python3 requests headers. What is the module name?

Edit: I am not searching for bs4, instead i am searching for what `sqlmap -r`
does. I want to implement functionality similar to `sqlmap -r` but it was a module rather than what sqlmap is doing, and it made a variable with all the HTTP header set such as cookie, host etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I remembered now. The module is called burpee. https://github.com/xscorp/Burpee.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question, you are searching the module name  that burp suite is using to display the text from the request. If it's that, bs4 (beautiful soup 4) could be the module.